# Flexbox evenly sized elements regardless of contents

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

## How to size each square the same???

[Preview Issue on JSBIN](http://output.jsbin.com/nurumi/1/quiet) | [View Issue Code on JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/nurumi/1/edit?html,css)

I am using **flexbox** to create a grid layout.  Most grid cells do not have content and some grid cells do have content.  When a cell has content it throws everything off.  **how can I make sure all cells are even regardless of content?**

[image: Not sized correctly]

#### HTML

I have three rows, each with three cells.  Only the center row of the center cell contains children.

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span>contains span</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

In the css the center space is larger than the other squares.

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body>div {
  display: flex;
}

body>div>div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You shall use `flex-basis` to specify the initial length of the flexible item.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body>div {
  display: flex;
}

body>div>div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 80px; /*set the initial length*/
}

body>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span>contains span asdsa asd asd asd asdsad ads asd sad</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why 80px?  How do you know 80px when the width depends upon the browser size?

Comment: It could be percentage. Not necessarily px but I gave it just as an example

Comment: setting `flex-basis: 0` will do if you just want to spread evenly

Comment: `flex-basis: 0` is the key to solving this issue imo. Thanks @Icycool

Answer (score 54):

You are using `flex-grow: 1`. That means that the initial width of the flex items will be the width of its content, and then the available space will be distributed equally.

However, you want the flex items to have the same width, so you want to ignore the width of their content. You can achieve this with

```css
flex: 1;
```

Additionally, Flexbox introduces `auto` as the initial value of `min-width`. This might produce different widths in some cases, so to be safe better add `min-width: 0` or set `overflow` to anything but `visible`

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
body > div {
  display: flex;
}
body > div > div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
div {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}
body > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div><span>contains span</span></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and it works because `flex` is shorthand for; flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. The defaults for those are; 0, 1 and auto respectively. So the longhand solution would be: `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: 0;`. Note that `flex-basis` is 0, not the default `auto`, because if you set `flex` with a single number value, the default is really like `1 0` (the same as omitting flex-basis). It is recommended to use the shorthand version.

Comment: I had a problem where you could resize the flexbox to grow, but once the flexbox grew it couldn't be shrunk again. `min-width: 0;` solved everything for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of setting a 33% `flex-basis`

```
  body>div>div {
      border: solid 1px blue;
      flex: 0 0 33%;
    }
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body>div {
  display: flex;
}

body>div>div {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}

div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

body>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
   <div>
      <div></div>
      <div><span>contains span</span></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
   <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
      
   <div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `flex: 1 0 0` on the child elements.

The problem with the current answers is they either don't explicitly set the flex-basis to 0 or rely on fixed or percentage widths which assumes you know how many comlumns there are. In some cases you might have a variable amount of columns and still want to distribute the available space evenly between the child elements.

This is shorthand for `flex-grow: 1;`, `flex-shrink: 0;`, `flex-basis: 0;`.
By setting `flex-basis` to 0, you're asking the browser to not take the natural width of the element into account when calculating how to distribute the spacing with `flex-grow: 1;`.

See the MDN explaination here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Controlling_Ratios_of_Flex_Items_Along_the_Main_Ax

[image: variable columns, equally distributed space]

Here's the code with both 3 and 4 column examples

```
<div class="flex">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <div></div>
    <div><span>contains span</span></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
    <div></div>
    <div><span>contains span</span></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

```
<style lang="text/css">
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.flex > div {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
```